# Returning view from Spring MVC @RestController

Tags: java, spring-mvc

As `@RestController` is composition of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`, I believe if I want my controller to work as both
MVC and REST controller just annotating with `@RestController` should be fine. Is that correct?

As `@RestController` is composition of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody,` I think it internally means that it's good for

1. Receiving the http request (because of `@Controller`)
2. Sending the response in JSON format (because of `@ResponseBody`) though it can be changed if required

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`@RestController` is not meant to be used to return views to be resolved. It is supposed to return data which will be written to the body of the response, hence the inclusion of `@ResponseBody`. You can not selectively disable the `@ResponseBody` on individual handler methods when `@ResponseBody` is already annotation on class level.

You can work around it by returning `ModelAndView`, which will work even in `@RestController`, but you *really shouldn't*:

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView renderFooList() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("foo/list");
    mav.addObject("foos", fooService.getFoos());
    return mav;
}
```

It would be better to create separate controllers for normal handlers returning views and REST controllers for the RESTful stuff. Or to annotate the class with plain `@Controller` and put `@ResponseBody` on the methods where you actually need it.

Comment: Can you please explain why ModelAndView alone ignored by RestController/ResponseBody? Also is there any list of classes which will not be converted to json by RestController/ResponseBody?

Answer (score 3):

@RestController annotation, which marks this class as a controller where every method returns a domain object/pojo instead of a view. It means that we are no more using view-resolvers, we are no more directly sending the html in response but we are sending domain object converted into format understood by the consumers.