# SpringBoot ViewController is ignored if @RestController is added

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I was doing some spring boot examples.

One was like below;

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    @GetMapping("/verify")
    public String showForm(PersonForm personForm) {
        return "form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/verify")
    public String checkPersonInfo(@Valid PersonForm personForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "form";
        }
        return "redirect:/results";
    }
}
```

and the Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/results").setViewName("results");
    }
}
```

Which works fine.

**However, if i add a `RestController` like below, all the invalid urls that does not exist is mapped to the below class (including root "/"). I do not get a WhiteLabel Error Page anymore. Also the `results` view mapped to this class**

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String baseTemplate = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping(name = "/greeting")
    public Greeting greet(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(baseTemplate, name));
    }
}
```

Why is `WebMvcConfiguration` gets ignored when i add `RestController`? What i am doing wrong here?

**NOTE:** I used Spring Boot Version `1.4.3.RELEASE`.

**Some LOG** :

```
[12:59:03.824][DEBUG][http-nio-8080-exec-1][o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet]DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/results]
[12:59:03.828][DEBUG][http-nio-8080-exec-1][o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /results
[12:59:03.835][DEBUG][http-nio-8080-exec-1][o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Returning handler method [public com.sample.boot.model.Greeting com.sample.boot.controller.GreetingController.greet(java.lang.String)]
[12:59:03.836][DEBUG][http-nio-8080-exec-1][o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet] Last-Modified value for [/results] is: -1
[12:59:03.920][DEBUG][http-nio-8080-exec-1][o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor] Written [com.sample.boot.model.Greeting@19aea6b5] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@16a2ed51]
[12:59:03.921][DEBUG][http-nio-8080-exec-1][o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
[12:59:03.921][DEBUG][http-nio-8080-exec-1][o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet] Successfully completed request
```

Comment: It is not clear. you are returning an instance of Greeting and what you are expecting here ?. RestController is a combination of Controller + ResponseBody . doc :https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html

Comment: @Barath: i think you did not read full question. Also please check log. I do a request for `/results` view but i gets returned `/greeting`

Comment: RestController is not a view controller. If you enable RestController its not using view-resolvers anymore

Comment: @Patrick: Is there a way to get around that? Or i can never use `@RestController` in a service which have view-resolvers?

Comment: @Rajkishan not really sure. But look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33062952/3493036). Could help you