# Thymeleaf template/ view not found - Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm setting up a new SPring4 app using Thymeleaf and keep encountering the same issue when it comes to returning the view.  I've searched don here and followed some online tutorials but the same error so I'm thinking it may be due to configuration, any help is appreciated, thanks.

The error : `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

And then my config is:

Web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Use the simplified configuration by default. -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>simple</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <param-value>simple</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<display-name>Test Web Application</display-name>
```

mcv.xml:

```
    <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!--Allows for static content to easily be served up without needing a controller etc-->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/assets/img/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/" location="/assets/css/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/"/>

    <!--taken from the thymeleaf site-->
    <bean id="templateResolver"
          class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine"
          class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

rootcontext.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <import resource="mvc.xml" />

    <!--double asterisk allows for recursive search - load all under the pacakge-->
    <context:component-scan
            base-package="
                com.example.*"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>


</beans>
```

Edit:

Controller:

```
@Controller //restcontroller is not meant to be for returning view, but instead the data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062509/returning-view-from-spring-mvc-restcontroller
```

@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class EmrController {

```
@Autowired EmrService emr;

@ModelAttribute("emrClusterList")
private List<EmrCluster>getAllClusters(){ return emr.getRunningClusters(); }

@RequestMapping(value = "/EmrClusters", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayEmrList(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("emrClusterList", emr.getRunningClusters());
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the page by the URL on the browser ? or are you invoking a controller and the response in the controller is not returning correctly the page ?

Comment: a controller is being invoked and the requested page is not being returned

Comment: Please add the code of the controller.

Comment: Controller has been added

Comment: this file exists  /WEB-INF/views/index.html ?

Comment: @reos - yes.  It doesn't make sense :(

Structure is src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.html