# I want to expose my existing controller as a Restful service

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have an application where I'm registering a user so user will enter his data on JSP page and the data will be save into DB, the flow will be `JSP->dispatcher->controller->Service->Dao`.
Now in MemberController which is delegating the  request to the Service, has a method `register()` which will take the MemberDto as a parameter now and return the Successfull msg to the `success.jsp` page. Sometihng like user registered successfully.

```
public String Register(MemberDto memberDto)
```

Now I want to expose this same method as RestFul service using Jersey for partners and also use this same method within my application as a normal MVC flow. How can I acheive this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So u want to use Jersey so import the jersey library to support JAX-RS.

```
@Path("/classlevelpath")
public class MyController {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION-XML)
    @Path("/register")
    public String Register(MemberDto memberDto) {

    }
}
```

Be careful JAX-RS (Jersey is an implementaion) and Spring REST annotations are different.

Comment: '@Path("/classlvlpath")
public class MyController {
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION-XML)
@Path("/register")
 public String Register(Model model,@ModelAttribute MemberDto memberDto),BindingResult errors {
model.addAttribute("msg",new User("admin","a@g.com"));return "success";
    }
}'
if i expose this method as rest it will return "success" as part of the response in rest client ,and if i will use this code in normal spring MVC to submit the data from member-reg.jsp to controller then it persist the data in DB and displlay user object on success,jsp page , 
so what should i do ?

Comment: in that case u have to keep 2 different public apis which willl use same businessservice logic. The api for jsp should return the view name. this view name should be resolved by the view resolver which is configured in spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml. the 2nd api should be restful which should be annotated with "@Responsebody". Annotate ur controller with "@controller" not with "@restcontroller"

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your rest class with `@RestController`. The best practice is to create another controller. By you can see this answer if you want to transform your existing controller: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062509/returning-view-from-spring-mvc-restcontroller`

Comment: if i mark my existing controller with @RestController then will this work with my member-registratioon.jsp which is already using that controller for registering or my member-regisrtaio.jsp also has to consume that serive by sending ajax request ?