# How to return both content data and pagename from a single controller in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm doing a project in spring boot. After finishing all the API part and moving on towards frontend part, I realised that `@RestController` annotated controller can only return data and not the page names. I got a solution to create another controller with `@Controller` annotation and fetch the API data with Javascript upon pageload. This is okay but it'll require me to create a nother set of urls and controllers for each of my entities which sounds unnecessrily time wastage. 
Is there any way of returning both page name and JSON data together from `@RestController`?? as in Django and laravels.

Comment: Spring's guide, [Consuming a RESTful Web Service with AngularJS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/) may help.

Comment: you want to return the page and json at the same time in the new page?

Comment: Yes @BishalGautam

Answer (score 1):

**You could try to wrap your controller data in a specific object like**

```
abstract class AbstractResponse {
    String pageName;
}

class MyResponse extends  AbstractResponse{
    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;
    String field4;
}
```

**What will give you something like in json**

```
{
  "field1": "",
  "field2": "",
  "field3": "",
  "field4": "",
  "pageName": ""
}
```

**Or use the modelAndView concept like discuss in this post**
[Returning view from Spring MVC @RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062509/returning-view-from-spring-mvc-restcontroller)