# how to to download a excel file in a restController

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Heloo all,

I need to make a rest application which allow to download a excel file with some information's from my db, I found a example on the web but this one use a Controller with a model. In my case I need  to create a rest api with a @restController I would like to know how to change this exemple so that it works with a rest method

This is the controller

```
@Controller
public class ExportController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    /**
     * Handle request to download an Excel document
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String download(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAllUsers());
        return "";
    }
}
```

This is the excel view:

```
public class ExcelView extends AbstractXlsView {

    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
                                      Workbook workbook,
                                      HttpServletRequest request,
                                      HttpServletResponse response) {

        // change the file name
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"my-xls-file.xls\"");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> users = (List<User>) model.get("users");

        // create excel xls sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("User Detail");
        sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(30);




        // create header row
        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Firstname");

        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("LastName");

        header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Age");

        header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Job Title");

        header.createCell(4).setCellValue("Company");

        header.createCell(5).setCellValue("Address");

        header.createCell(6).setCellValue("City");

        header.createCell(7).setCellValue("Country");

        header.createCell(8).setCellValue("Phone Number");



        int rowCount = 1;

        for (User user : users) {
            Row userRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            userRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(user.getFirstName());
            userRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(user.getLastName());
            userRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(user.getAge());
            userRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(user.getJobTitle());
            userRow.createCell(4).setCellValue(user.getCompany());
            userRow.createCell(5).setCellValue(user.getAddress());
            userRow.createCell(6).setCellValue(user.getCity());
            userRow.createCell(7).setCellValue(user.getCountry());
            userRow.createCell(8).setCellValue(user.getPhoneNumber());

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: see that answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062509/returning-view-from-spring-mvc-restcontroller