# How to implement REST API on a RestController using ModelAndView

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Im struggling on how to implement a API when the methods in my controller are returning a ModelAndView. Most tutorials I can find are returning ResponseEntities. Should i be making seperate API controllers which strictly handle the API calls under a /api mapping? (which i believe isn't  RESTFUL practice). Or is it possible to handle my API calls in the same controller, even when making use of ModelAndView?

My controller looks as following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dish")
public class DishController {

    private final DishRepository dishRepository;

    public DishController(DishRepository dishRepository) {
        this.dishRepository = dishRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView list() {
        Iterable<Dish> dishes = this.dishRepository.findAll();
        return new ModelAndView("dishes/list", "dishes", dishes);
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ModelAndView view(@PathVariable("id") Dish dish) {
        return new ModelAndView("dishes/view", "dish", dish);
    }

    @GetMapping(params = "form")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String createForm(@ModelAttribute Dish dish) {
        return "dishes/form";
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public ModelAndView create(@Valid Dish dish, BindingResult result,
                               RedirectAttributes redirect) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("dishes/form", "formErrors", result.getAllErrors());
        }
        dish = this.dishRepository.save(dish);
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("globalMessage", "view.success");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/d/{dish.id}", "dish.id", dish.getId());
    }

    @RequestMapping("foo")
    public String foo() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Expected exception in controller");
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @GetMapping("delete/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        this.dishRepository.deleteById(id);
        Iterable<Dish> dishes = this.dishRepository.findAll();
        return new ModelAndView("dishes/list", "dishes", dishes);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @GetMapping("/modify/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public ModelAndView modifyForm(@PathVariable("id") Dish dish) {
        return new ModelAndView("dishes/form", "dish", dish);
    }
```

Comment: The question is more of a design choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RestController` is a shorthand for writing `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`, which you should only use if all methods are returning an object that should be treated as the response body (eg. JSON).

If you want to combine both REST endpoints and MVC endpoints within the same controller, you can annotate it with `@Controller` and individually annotate each method with `@ResponseBody`.

For example:

```java
@Controller // Use @Controller in stead of @RestController
@RequestMapping("/dish")
public class DishController {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public ModelAndView list() { /* ... */ }

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody // Use @ResponseBody for REST API methods
    public List<Dish> findAll() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Alternatively, as you've mentioned, you can use multiple controllers:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dish")
public class DishViewController { /* ... */ }

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/dish")
public class DishAPIController { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thanks that clears thing up alot! I think i'll go with multiple controllers then

Comment: @Bram Sounds like a good idea. I usually also separate my API controller mappings from my API controller mappings.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use Model and View in RestController. The main goal of RestController is to return data, not views. Take a look here for more details: [Returning view from Spring MVC @RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062509/returning-view-from-spring-mvc-restcontroller).