# Spring Mvc Controller Get Endpoint not redirecting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hello I am having some trouble in my `Controller` class. All requests work fine except for this one which for some reason refuses to redirect me to another page even though I am doing everything fine as far as I know.
Here is my Controller class.
The problem is with the `beginReservation` endpoint

```
package movie_manager.web.presentation;

import movie_manager.model.dto.MovieDto;
import movie_manager.model.dto.ReservationDto;
import movie_manager.model.dto.UserDto;
import movie_manager.model.pojo.FormPojo;
import movie_manager.model.pojo.ReservationPojo;
import movie_manager.service.MovieService;
import movie_manager.service.ReservationService;
import movie_manager.service.UserService;
import movie_manager.web.session.SessionInfo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private SessionInfo sessionInfo;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;

    @Autowired
    private ReservationService reservationService;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView userPage(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user");
        Collection<MovieDto> movies = movieService.getAll();
        modelAndView.addObject("movies", movies);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("view_movie/{movieId}")
    public ModelAndView viewMovie(@Valid @PathVariable long movieId){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("view_movie");
        modelAndView.addObject("movie", movieService.get(movieId));
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping("/make_reservation")
    public void makeReservation(@Valid @RequestBody FormPojo formPojo){
        MovieDto movieDto = movieService.get(formPojo.movieId);
        UserDto userDto = sessionInfo.getUser();
        ReservationDto reservationDto = new ReservationDto();
        reservationDto.movieDto = movieDto;
        reservationDto.userDto = userDto;
        reservationDto.userName = formPojo.userName;
        reservationService.add(reservationDto);
    }

    @GetMapping("/begin_reservation")
    public ModelAndView beginReservation(@Valid @RequestBody ReservationPojo reservationPojo) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("reservation");
        MovieDto movieDto = movieService.get(reservationPojo.movieId);
        if(movieDto.availableSeats < reservationPojo.numberOfSeats)
            return new ModelAndView("notEnoughSeats");
        modelAndView.addObject("movie", movieDto);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i< reservationPojo.numberOfSeats;i++){
            list.add(i);
        }
        modelAndView.addObject("numberOfForms", list);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

All other endpoints work just fine. And the problematic endpoint is reached successfully. The issue seems to be with the `ModelAndView` object. The page just stays static no errors no nothing. I would also note that no path seems to work(even those used above in other endpoints).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And why should it? It is an `@RestController` used to indicate it should send JSON/XML to the client, no redirects. Use an `@Controller` instesad of `@RestController`. It is also a bit weird to send a JSON request and render a view in return.

Comment: A similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062509/returning-view-from-spring-mvc-restcontroller). See if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RestController` is not meant to be used to return views to be resolved. It is supposed to return data which will be written to the body of the response, hence the inclusion of `@ResponseBody`. You can not selectively disable the `@ResponseBody` on individual handler methods when `@ResponseBody` is already annotation on class level.

Original answer here [Returning view from Spring MVC @RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062509/returning-view-from-spring-mvc-restcontroller).